# PHP Regex to capture names if prefixed with key words

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I'm in need of a PHP regular expression to capture the first initial an last name of people listed in a text document.  But only capture the names when the sentence or line contains a few keywords. (from, with, of, and ,as ,observed).  My current attempt captures list items ie.  "A. General" or "B. Issues" because it doesn't seem to care about what's in front of the names.

I've been using preg_match_all() with hopes of it returning an array of names. (first inital, last name).

### Example text

```
"from J. Smith and B. Miller"
"as T. Baker observed M. Kelly"
"We inquired with B. Brown, T. Stark and J. Maddox."
```

I've tried

- $regex = "/[from|with|of|and|as|observed|,|.]\s+([A-Z]. \w+)/";
- $regex = "/((from|with|of|and|as|observed|,|.)\s+([A-Z]. \w+))/";
- $regex = "/\b(from|with|of|and|as|observed|,|.)\s+([A-Z].\ \w+)/";
- $regex = "/\b(from|with|of|and|as|observed|,|.|\b)\s+([A-Z].\ \w+)/";

I cannot make it only capture when the word list is before the names.   I can't use ^ to check 'starts with'.  I'm horrible at regex and guess until it works.  I feel the solution requires some sort of look-behind assertion, though I'm not sure how it works.

### Output

Should be an array

- [ 'J. Smith', 'B. Miller' ]
- [ 'T. Baker', 'M. Kelly' ]
- [ 'B. Brown', 'T. Stark', 'J. Maddox' ]

#### UPDATE

### Final Regexp

- $regex = "/\b(?:from|with|of|and|as|observed|,)\s+([A-Z].\ \w+)/";

Seems to work with the few documents I have.  Thanks everyone!!

Comment: How is a RegEx supposed to know that *"We inquired"* or, indeed, *"B. Issues"* is **not** a name? I assume this text file has some kind of rigid structure?

Comment: [Your thrid regex works well](https://regex101.com/r/dhJBKm/1). The result is in `$matches[2]`. You just need to escape `.`. Like [here](https://regex101.com/r/dhJBKm/2).

Comment: @CD001 There is a fairly rigid structure.  The trigger should be the keywords.  From, With, Of, And, As, Observed.  "B. Issues" doesn't start with that.  I asked myself that exact same question.  I'm not good with these and I'm throwing in the towel and asking here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, I see that now.  Not sure why I didn't escape the period.  Understand regexp enough to get by and use the phpliveregex website often.  Thanks

Comment: @tlorens I had 2 concerns basically, 1) RegEx matching on names usually ends in tears: *Jan van den Haag*, *Tim O'Reilly* or 周润发 for example. 2) without a regular structure, Regular Expressions will struggle.

Comment: @CD001 True story and I totally agree.  We have a team of people who follow very specific set of rules when documenting things.  Anything here is better than the results I get now.  The app is internal and we can deal with edge cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this modified version of your third regex :

```
\b(?:from|with|of|and|as|observed|,)\s+([A-Z].\ \w+)\g
```

<s>You need to escape `.` in the first group or it will accept any character.</s> Not relevant after edit

The `\g` flag will find every occurrence of the pattern, and you will be able to access the results in `$matches[1]`.

(The added `?:` in first group prevent it from being captured, you can remove it if you need to know the keyword, but then the results will be stored in $matches[2] )

Edit : Removed `\.` in first group to not match end of sentences (see author comment).

Comment: I used this with a minor modification.  Removing the \. in the first grouping.  It would grab the beginning of a sentence. "We watched as J. Smith and B. Brown"... "We watched" would be included as a name.    Thanks!!

Comment: That's true ! I will modify my answer with your modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking for a capital letter followed by a dot and a word

```
[A-Z]\.\s\w+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
/(?!^from|with|of|and|as|observed|\s)([A-Z]{1,}\.\s\w*)/g
```

Where

?! = Discard the match of the first group, that begins with first `(` and ends with `)` and at least is included also the \s (space) at the beginning of the name.

^ = match the *begins* of the line/sentence/string

Then in second group it should match just one capital letter `{1,}` and then a dot `\.`, a space `\s` and the word `\w`

The `/g` at the end stands for "global search"

https://regexr.com/3pa9o

Comment: Unfortunately, this matches on 'A. General' which is a title for a section in the document.   i don't expect everyone to understand the full context of this.  I also can't post the actual contents.    Thanks for the effort.